# Where does the most active EOS community reside? IRC? Telegram? Slack?

Tags: development

Where is the active eos developer community reside? Do they hangout in IRC? Slack? Telegram? I don't care for eos speculation trading chatrooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, the [EOS Developers Telegram](https://t.me/joinchat/EaEnSUPktgfoI-XPfMYtcQ) is probably the most active international community of EOS devs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of telegram channel about eos and future development. For instance:

- https://t.me/eosrex for eos REX
- https://t.me/eoscanada eos Canada
- https://t.me/eoslynx eos Lynx
- https://t.me/joinchat/AAAAAEQbOeucnaMWN0A9dQ eos general discussion chat

There are a lot of other channel...